# Call server side function after AsyncFileUpload complete upload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I don't know why calling another function inside the `OnUploadedComplete` does not work in ordinary way, It's my code:
ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                OnUploadedComplete ="UploadFile1" 
                OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" ThrobberID="myThrobber" 
                onclientuploaderror="uploadError" CompleteBackColor="White" />
```

VB.NET code:

```
Protected Sub UploadFile1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'saveing file on disk, this part works fine, but calling 
    'myfunction() does not work properly
    myfunction()
End Sub

Sub myfunction()
    mylabel.Text="done" 'this does not work
    insert_records_to_db() 'this works
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the client side javascript functions (uploadComplete, uploadError) work?

Comment: they work, I want to call another server-side function inside the UploadFile1.

Comment: ops, my bad! it calls that insider function, but changing label text does not work in that function :/

Comment: The AsyncFileUpload is still making use of the iframe to make the asynchronous upload possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because an AsyncFileUpload-Control is rendered in an IFrame(normally a FileUpload is only possible with full postbacks due to security reasons), therefore it does not have the normal behaviour of UpdatePanels.

You can workaround it by handling the clientside `OnClientUploadComplete` to trigger a hidden button that causes an asynchronous postback.

```
OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"

function uploadComplete() {
   $get("<%=btnShowUploadResult.ClientID %>").click();
}

<asp:Button ID="btnShowUploadResult" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="hidden" Style="display: none" />
```

You can store your message in the serverside `OnUploadedComplete` into a Session variable and read it in `btnShowUploadResult.Click` handler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's due to how the AsyncFileUpload control works, see [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1479864.aspx) for more information.

Couldn't you just use the client side javascript function to change your label text?

Comment: it's not a simple text, It should retrieve some data from db and update literal with  them, those data are some image URLs.