# How to store a value during partial postback inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, hidden-field

I have a ajax file upload inside my update panel to upload the file immediately after the user selects a file to upload. During the file upload in `btnVidUpload_Click` I assign the file name to the hidden field which is also inside the update panel. Then when I click Submit Send_Click tries to get the value from the hidden field, but the hidden field is empty, why is the hidden field losing its value, cant it retain the value during post back or is there a way to store the value without using session. thanks

```
 <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AFU_Video" OnUploadedComplete="btnVidUpload_Click"   
     runat="server" UploaderStyle="Traditional" ThrobberID="aajaxLoader" />

 <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidd_VideoLoc" runat="server" />

 </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

 <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Send" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Send_Click"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AsyncFileUpload` internally uses an iFrame to render the `FileUpload` control.
That is the reason why it seems to lose it's value.

You need to use the Session in `btnVidUpload_Click`.

Own answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495986/284240

Comment: So there is no other option than using the session to store the value

Comment: I would say the Session is the best way to store this value temporarily. I'm not sure what your submit button does. Maybe you want to trigger it automatically directly after the file was uploaded. Then you can clear the Session immediately. See the link in my answer for an example.